Insert unique_ptr in a map and keep ownership of unique_ptr on failed insertion
I have a method addToMap that accepts a string as a key and an unique_ptr as value that should then be emplaced in a map.
If the insertion fails the caller of the method should keep the ownership. For the method emplace(...)  in the map class this is possible. How can I achieve that behaviour for my addToMap method?
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    void addToMap(const std::string& key, std::unique_ptr<int> value)
    {
        _map.emplace(key, std::move(value));
        // after a failed insertion value is not empty and usable
    }

    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<int>> _map;
};

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_unique<int>(0);
    auto b = std::make_unique<int>(1);

    Foo foo;
    foo.addToMap("0", std::move(a)); // a is now empty
    foo.addToMap("0", std::move(b)); // b is now empty too, but it should not be
}


First of all, use try_emplace instead.

std::unique_ptr<int>&& value for the parameter.

Second, use a rvalue reference && as argument (as mentioned by @Eljay) and don't use std::move.

@Someprogrammerdude what should I use instead of std::move? The intention of the method is to move the ownership? But the rvalue reference worked. Thanks!

Using l-value reference might make sense BTW.

using move is okay since that just casts the reference type. It's more a matter of convention. I'd say stay with rvalue reference (which also requires move to make it usable, obviously) but the only meaningful difference to an lvalue reference is that you can write addMap("0", std::make_unique<int>(0)), which doesn't work with lvalues. That rvalues remain unchanged and available to the caller in case of errors is common and for example common for C++ standard containers in case of exceptions. People just don't always expect that, so document that behavior
